# Method B is used in Method A; in an inherited class, make A use overridden B

Tags: c#, inheritance

For example, in the following class, suppose `Say()` is a relatively long method. Everything else is fine, but I want to do something else for `GetWords()`. I create an inherited class, and make `GetWords()` do something else. But its `Say()` method will still use the `GetWords()` of the parent class.

Is there a way to achieve this without overriding `Say()` in the inherited class and copy-and-pasting the method body? The `Dog` class is already implemented like that, but I can change it anyway I want as necessary.

```
Doge d = new Doge();
d.Say(); //says `Rrrrrrrr`.

public class Dog
{
    public void Say()
    {
         // Do a lot of stuff
        var words = GetWords();
        Debug.WriteLine(words);
         // Do a lot of other stuff
    }

    protected string GetWords()
    {
        return "Rrrrrrrr";
    }    
}

public class Doge:Dog
{
    protected new string GetWords()
    {
        return "Such inheritance";
    }    
}
```

Comment: So you want it to print out `Such inheritance`?

Comment: Yes, for this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In dog change GetWords to

```
protected virtual string GetWords()
```

In doge use

```
 protected override string GetWords()
```